# Update Datagridview When the network database data changed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I with multiple clients connected to the database using below connection:

```
Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

How can when the database changed (insert || update || delete) all client datagridview information be updated ?? (I using SQL Server 2012)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

to update grid data you have to make thread that will check data update if data updated then bring data from that thread and update grid data source

Answer (score 0):

this is my class

```
public class ManageNotificationUtil
{
    private BackgroundWorker NotificationWorker;
    private Timer timerNotification;
    private Form ParentForm;
    private NotificationDetailData NotificationDetail;
    public ManageNotificationUtil()
    {
        //NotificationWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        //timerNotification = new Timer();
        //NotificationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        //InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ManageNotificationUtil(Form owner)
    {
        ParentForm = owner;
        NotificationWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
        NotificationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        timerNotification = new Timer();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.timerNotification.Enabled = true;
        this.timerNotification.Interval = 60000;
        this.timerNotification.Tick += new EventHandler(timerNotification_Tick);
        this.NotificationWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(NotificationWorker_DoWork);
        NotificationWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(NotificationWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }
    private void NotificationWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        NotificationDetail = NotificationBD.GetNotificationDataByReceiverUserName(SessionManagerUI.UserSessionDetails.UserDetails.LoginUserName);

    }

    private void NotificationWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NotificationDetail != null)
        {
            if (NotificationDetail.NotificationList != null)
            {
                if (NotificationDetail.NotificationList.Count > 0)
                {
                    NotificationAlertControlUtility notificationAlertControlUtility;
                    foreach (NotificationData Notification in NotificationDetail.NotificationList)
                    {
                        notificationAlertControlUtility = new NotificationAlertControlUtility(Notification);
                        notificationAlertControlUtility.AlertControlShowConformation(ParentForm);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void timerNotification_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!NotificationWorker.IsBusy && SessionManagerUI.SessionDetails != null)
        {
            NotificationWorker.RunWorkerAsync(0);
        }
    }
    public void disposeItems()
    {

    }
}
```

i have use this class to show notification that is stored in database 
you can change it according to need